# Troubles using docker-machine to setup Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I have a problem with deploying local virtualbox based swarm - I have followed the instructions in the official docker documentation regarding setting up master/worker nodes using the docker-machine tool. I have created the token on dockerhub and used --swarm (and --swarm-master) with --swarm-discovery token://XXXX ... so far so good, two machines running, seemingly registered as the Swarm master and worker:

```
spaceback@brutus:~$ docker-machine ls
NAME           ACTIVE      DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM                   DOCKER    ERRORS
swarm-master   * (swarm)   virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376   swarm-master (master)   v1.12.0   
swarm-node1    -           virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376   swarm-master            v1.12.0   
spaceback@brutus:~$ docker run --rm swarm list token://[....]
192.168.99.101:2376
192.168.99.100:2376
```

and after setting the correct environment values using the "eval $(docker-machine env --swarm swarm-master)" I can get status using the "docker info" stating that I have two nodes running...
but any attempt to run any other docker swarm commands (docker node..., docker service...) I get "Error response from daemon: 404 page not found".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears you're attempting to use the new [swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) features against the older [docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/).

The following script creates a HA Swarm cluster with 3 managers and 2 workers (using Docker 1.12.0):

```
#=========================
# Creating cluster members
#=========================
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox node1
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox node2
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox node3
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox node4
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox node5

#===============
# Starting swarm
#===============
MANAGER_IP=$(docker-machine ip node1)

docker-machine ssh node1 docker swarm init --advertise-addr $MANAGER_IP

#===============
# Adding members
#===============
MANAGER_TOKEN=$(docker-machine ssh node1 docker swarm join-token --quiet manager)
WORKER_TOKEN=$(docker-machine ssh node1 docker swarm join-token --quiet worker)

docker-machine ssh node2 docker swarm join --token $MANAGER_TOKEN $MANAGER_IP:2377
docker-machine ssh node3 docker swarm join --token $MANAGER_TOKEN $MANAGER_IP:2377
docker-machine ssh node4 docker swarm join --token $WORKER_TOKEN  $MANAGER_IP:2377
docker-machine ssh node5 docker swarm join --token $WORKER_TOKEN  $MANAGER_IP:2377
```

List the swarm members

```
$ docker-machine ssh node1 docker node ls
ID                           HOSTNAME  STATUS  AVAILABILITY  MANAGER STATUS
4s0mrh2u4sa2p260ung8ipb0m *  node1     Ready   Active        Leader
5ra7b8cwarpcpa47p2gq2ecxs    node2     Ready   Active        Reachable
66t3pq66ynlvyl3do6lpn9kzb    node3     Ready   Active        
7k5n1id2q6yncqjbv7l8ec0r5    node5     Ready   Active        
833e4ya58hq62epplreyvwtnm    node4     Ready   Active
```

Creating a service

```
$ docker-machine ssh node1 docker service create --name web --replicas=10 -p 30000:80 nginx

$ docker-machine ssh node1 docker service ps web
ID                         NAME    IMAGE  NODE   DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE           ERROR
2fxy4n57p8ot3mn0kws96pnuk  web.1   nginx  node1  Running        Running 30 seconds ago  
cmm1s3h8ds7tmppf7pwvl5zxw  web.2   nginx  node5  Running        Running 6 seconds ago   
7ixgtqlz049ggi90363js088b  web.3   nginx  node1  Running        Running 30 seconds ago  
4o1e2wkh0x4rp8h9o73as8drf  web.4   nginx  node3  Running        Running 22 seconds ago  
6lufnzzddljlw0lnu0qyftzh6  web.5   nginx  node3  Running        Running 22 seconds ago  
49g43g23t4r9lpmitfs4uu1j6  web.6   nginx  node2  Running        Running 3 seconds ago   
43dopngi08licw4xttipnfdb6  web.7   nginx  node2  Running        Running 3 seconds ago   
8d47dvmokf65xb271fyk3jlbu  web.8   nginx  node4  Running        Running 7 seconds ago   
2t56edm3k4x98yjkvgamyq6v4  web.9   nginx  node5  Running        Running 6 seconds ago   
byij5j5pom1t3elu2ydteasg7  web.10  nginx  node4  Running        Running 7 seconds ago
```

Comment: aha... well, I can script it that way (or do the swarm init/join steps manually), but I thought that the docker-machine's --swarm* group of options should set the swarm for me automagically, at least the docker-machine docs make it look so... so those are actually unusable to work with the new docker engine 1.12?

Comment: @JiříNovák Docker swarm has been integrated into the Docker engine in version 1.12. This is intended to replace the older Swarm, which ran  as containers. The swarm options in docker-machine were intended to make the older swarm easier to use. One can still use them, but then you cannot expect the new docker engine commands like "docker node" or "docker service" to work.

Comment: @mark-oconnor right, I got confused by the two versions of swarm, I found it out by some more searches and reading after I had few hours of sleep :) thanks for clarification...

Comment: After searching for long time i got this to work Thanks! Well done