# Docker swarm node hostnames are the same

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I use vagrant to manage VirtualBox and I want to build a cluster using Docker Swarm.

When I run the command `docker node ls` it shows the same hostname. Also if I run the service, they are run and shutdown immediately and run and shutdown.

[Here is the vagrant file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiHNb.png)
[Here is the docker swarm result show.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrkIQ.png)

Comment: Pictures of text data tend to be discouraged on SE, it makes it impossible for others to search for similar issues. Please provide the swarm init/join commands you ran (with tokens censored out) and the command you ran to submit your service, along with any Dockerfiles needed to recreate your scenario.

Comment: At first ,thank you very much for editing my question@Matt @BMitch And somehow and reboot the machine ,the hostname become distinct. maybe the problem can be describe: i can ping 192.168.33.12 throught ip,but i can't ping worker1 throught hostname . and the solution is :after install the vagrant hostmanager plugin we should reboot and the hostname will be distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest installing [docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) and then use the following script to install a swarm

[Troubles using docker-machine to setup Swarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38666566/troubles-using-docker-machine-to-setup-swarm/38668847#38668847)

Under the hood it still uses Virtualbox, just a more docker friendly way compared to vagrant.

Comment: thanks! this is a good idea and i will try it later. And somehow after i reboot the machine ,and it works . the hostname become distinct .

Answer (score 1):

Might be caused by this issue of changing the hostname before or after docker-engine:
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/27173

After I rebooted my VM, the HOSTNAME column was correct.